# how to add message when record doesn't exists....?

Tags: php, html

This is my full codes of HTML PHP table page. This is working, but when the record doesn't exist it doesn't display anything. So I want to display message when record doesn't exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Subjects</td>
      <td>Grades</td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results_teach)) {
    if($row["Sub_1"] != "" && $row["Sub_Grades_1"] != "") { 
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sub_1"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sub_Grades_1"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
      }
    $i++;
    }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check number of rows on result set. If 0 put up a message. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: how to apply it for these code..?

Comment: Look at the link and use the function on `$results_teach`... before the `while`.

Comment: please can you edit this - https://jsfiddle.net/75s6k91q/

Answer (score 0):

You have a counter called `$i`. You can simply check its value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Subjects</td>
      <td>Grades</td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results_teach)) {
    if($row["Sub_1"] != "" && $row["Sub_Grades_1"] != "") { 
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sub_1"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sub_Grades_1"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
      }
    $i++;
    }
?>
</table>
    <?php
    if ($i === 0) {
        ?>
            Does not exist
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the count of the fetched data via [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) function. If no data is fetched the count will be zero and you can display an error message

```php
if(mysqli_num_rows($results_teach) < 0){
   echo "The error message"
}else{
    $i=0;
    //code
}
```